# remove the IP address using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to remove this ip address `111.111.111.111` in my url
`http://111.111.111.111/sample/` using htaccess. How can I do that. I search here some example but only the removing folder. I have no idea on how to do this. Hoping for your help.

I want to display the url like this `http://sample/`

updated post
here's my htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/sample/(.*)$ http://sample/$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what do you want put at the place of ip?

Comment: sorry i update my post. i want to display http://sample/   url

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 111.111.111.111
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated after your update:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/sample/(.*)$ http://sample/$2 [L]
```

The first group captures your IP address, the second everything after sample. When you want to throw away the IP address, there is actually no need to capture it. It depends on what you are trying to achieve though.

Comment: I expect that the url will turn into (httpx://sample/). Please dont mine the x after http.